# Should I wait for DOMContentLoaded event if I place a script tag at the end of a body tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Should I wait for `DOMContentLoaded` event if I place a `script` tag with the corresponding JS file at the end of a `body` tag?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDOMContentLoaded);
```

Comment: No you don't. Unless you need to wait for other scripts to load first.

Comment: I wouldn't wait for it. You can query any DOM element from that script. To tie into any jQuery plugins you may have to listen to that event depending on the implementation of the plugin, or if your script addresses any variables from other scripts that are added after this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically no. If script modifies element, it needs to exist.
If you put script after that element it exists.
If you put it Before, it does not exist and you may want to use DOMContentLoaded to wait for script to execute until it's sure it exists.

```
<div id="myid"></div>
<script>
    getElementById('myid'); // it will work, Element myid Is defined
<script>
```

But this

```
<script>
    getElementById('myid'); // it will fail, it's not yet defined, it will be
    // Using DomContentLoaded here would be requrired
<script>
<div id="myid"></div>
```

Comment: would the second example work if we added attribute `async=true` to the script tag ?

Comment: async applies only to external files as far as I'm aware. Async tells browser not to "wait for http request". And execute script when it's ready. So it can happen Anytime.

Comment: True that ! Although the author includes an external file but your examples arent affected by async.
The idea being that script file requests are blocking requests unless async is mentioned.

Comment: Author does not ask about async, but asks about execution flow from what I understood. My answear is pointed at execution flow. Async can be unpredictable and is not recommended unless you know you need it.
Great resource about it: http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/ Defer would be more appropriate here.

Comment: thats a great resource ! Thanks for sharing ! Just wanted to discuss and extract more information out of you ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<script></script>` tag is for allowing client side scripting inside the code. When browser gets the HTML code , it first downloads all the script.
If they are not loaded dynamically like marked as defer or async, they'll load in sequential order.
The inline scripts are loaded after external scripts have been loaded first. 
There is no perfect order when you load scripts in async mode.

Comment: This doesn't directly and clearly answer the question. But it could be improved!